# Minitest: NoMethodError: undefined method `split' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby, testing, null, assert, minitest

This is my test:

```
test 'accepts nil first_name' do
  user = User.new(first_name: nil)
  assert_equal(nil, user.first_name)
end
```

When I run it, I am getting this error from minitest:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `split' for nil:NilClass
```

I can create the user manually in the console and it works, so I'm pretty sure the test should be passing.

Where is this `nil.split` coming from? My code does not use `split` anywhere.

Comment: What's your minitest version? Do you have a backtrace of that error?

Comment: minitest (5.13.0)

Comment: I have been unable to expose the line number, including with the `--trace` option. If you can tell me how to get that info, I'd love to learn.

Comment: I think because of the way you're using assert_equal, your minitest version and the lack of a backtrace, it might be happening [here](https://github.com/seattlerb/minitest/blob/3c6576a51f4e266996e3459d7a0dd054eb4c87f7/lib/minitest/assertions.rb#L225).

Comment: I suspect you're right. The line after that one offers the same advice as the answer below: ` warn "DEPRECATED: Use assert_nil if expecting nil from #{where}. This will fail in Minitest 6."`

Comment: Odd I don't see that deprecation warning show up. Maybe it got swallowed by something else along the way.

Answer (score 1):

Change this:

```
assert_equal(nil, user.first_name)
```

To this:

```
assert_nil(user.first_name)
```

I didn't dig down the stack deep enough to figure out what was being split where, but this fixed the problem.